# LinqToSql как убрать повторения из выборки по условию?

Tags: c#, база-данных, entity-framework, linq2sql

Запросом связываю 2 таблицы и выбираю нужные данные:

```
var result1 = dataEntities.Jobless.Join(dataEntities.PKType, // второй набор
                         p => p.Id, // свойство-селектор объекта из первого набора
                         t => t.Jobless_id, // свойство-селектор объекта из второго набора
                         (p, t) => new { Id = t.Id, Name = p.First_name, Pk = t.Type_pk, Date = t.PK_date }).Where(x => x.Pk == 1 
                         && x.Date >= period1 && x.Date <= period2); // результат
```

Но есть случаи, когда для `Jobless_id` есть много записей `PKType`, а надо выбрать только одну, самую новую, решил - у которой самый большой `Id`. Для этого надо как то идти запросом по нескольким записям, привязанным к одному `Id` и выбрать самый большой. 
Как это организовать?

P.S. Структура таблиц:
**PKType:**
- Id;
- PK_date;
- Type_pk;
- Jobless_id;
**Jobless:**
- Id;
- First_name;
и т.д.....

Comment: Неясно, что вы пытаетесь сделать. Получить первый элемент, подходящий под условие или, как гласит название, просто убрать повторения из выборки?

Comment: @AGS17 убрать повторения из выборки по условию (где повторения с одинаковым Jobless_id - учитывать только запись с самым большим Id)

Answer (score 1):

Нужно сгруппировать записи по Jobless_id и выбрать в каждой группе одну.

В лоб на сервере:

```
var q = from t in dataEntities.PKType
        where t.Type_pk == 1 && t.PK_date >= period1 && t.PK_date <= period2
        group t by t.Jobless_id into tg
        select tg.OrderByDescending(t => t.Id).FirstOrDefault()
```

У вас уже есть join - если превратить его в group join, группировка будет уже не нужна:

```
var q = from p in dataEntities.Jobless
        join t in dataEntities.PKType on p.Id equals t.Jobless_id into tg
        let t = tg.Where(t => t.Type_pk == 1 && t.PK_date >= period1 && t.PK_date <= period2)OrderByDescending(t => t.Id).FirstOrDefault()
        select new { ... }
```

А использование навигационных свойств позволяет и того избежать:

```
var q = from p in dataEntities.Jobless
        let t = p.PKTypes.Where(t => t.Type_pk == 1 && t.PK_date >= period1 && t.PK_date <= period2).OrderByDescending(t => t.Id).FirstOrDefault()
        select new { ... }
```

Comment: не выходит, во-первых не нравится ему `First()`, пишет "он используется только в конце выражения", а во вторых, исправив ошибку - результат, это просто общее количество записей. (

Comment: @Awesome7997 попробуйте заменить `First()` на `FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: так и сделал, результат - просто общее количество записей

Comment: @Awesome7997 значит, вы что-то сделали не так

Comment: Приведенные мною запросы никак не могут давать просто одно число в результате